# Flask: Define and use methods within templates

Tags: python, flask

Within Pocoo-Flask, how am I able to define and use methods within templates such as below? I am overall new to Python and subsequently the language's web frameworks.

```
{%
import socket

def DoesServiceExist(host, port):
    try:
        captive_dns_addr = socket.gethostbyname(host)
    except:
        pass

    try:
        host_addr = socket.gethostbyname(host)

        if (captive_dns_addr == host_addr):
            return False

        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.settimeout(1)
        s.connect((host, port))
        s.close()
    except:
        return False

    return True
%}
{% if DoesServiceExist("google.com", 80) %}
    <h1>Hello {{ name }}!</h1>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? are you trying to present a different page based on if a service exists?

Comment: I want to present text if that method returns true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than running a function in a view ([which is possible, they're called filters in jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#filters)) The better solution would be to have your view function give the template a pass / fail variable and change what the template does based on that pass fail.

```
def DoesServiceExist(host, port):
    try:
        captive_dns_addr = socket.gethostbyname(host)
    except:
        pass

    try:
        host_addr = socket.gethostbyname(host)

        if (captive_dns_addr == host_addr):
            return False

        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.settimeout(1)
        s.connect((host, port))
        s.close()
    except:
        return False

    return True

@app.route("/some_url")
def some_urls_view():
    ServiceExists = DoesServiceExist(host, port)
    name = getname() #I don't know what name is but you'll have to pass it to the template
    return render_template("some_template", ServiceExists=ServiceExists, name=name)
```

and then in a jinja2 template (in this case named "some_template")

```
{% if ServiceExists %}
    <h1>Hello {{ name }}!</h1>
{% else %}
    <h1>Hello!</h1>
{% endif %}
```

Every [keyword argument](http://docs.python.org/release/1.5.1p1/tut/keywordArgs.html) you pass to render_template will be globally available to the template when it's being rendered.

Comment: I tried to use what you have written but it doesn't work. The extra output doesn't show up.

@app.route('/servers')
def servers():
    ServiceExists = DoesServiceExist("youtube.com", 80)
    name = "YouTube"
    return render_template('servers.html', ServiceExists=ServiceExists, name=name)

{% if ServiceExists %}
    <h1>Hello {{ name }}!</h1>
{% endif %}

Comment: What's the value of ServiceExists? is it True or False?

Comment: I don't know how to print out in Flask, so I'm unsure.

Comment: One line before `render_template` put `print(ServiceExists)`

Comment: I did that. I looked through the console and didn't see anything.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37432/discussion-between-rawrgulmuffins-and-jire)